# Fast way to search for a series of keywords among articles

Tags: r, algorithm, nlp

To illustrate with an example:

I have a few keywords (case sensitive).

```
 kw <- c("American Express", "Inc said")
```

I have quite a few articles.

```
 data("acq")
 dv <- sapply(1:length(acq),function(x) acq[[x]]$content) #doing data transformation so that dv is just a vector of strings
```

I want the following table as an output

```
temp <- sapply(1:length(kw),function(x) stringr::str_detect(dv,kw[x]))
```

The problem is, I have millions of records and the method that I am using is not efficient enough.

Comment: Iterate over the keywords, not the records! They way you're going about it results in a function call for every record: millions of records, millions of function calls.

Comment: how exactly do I loop over the keywords though? I thought no matter what, I would have to loop over the keywords as well as the records? @RitchieSacramento

Comment: `str_detect()` will check every element in a vector.  However, you should post an example of the structure of your data (use something like `dput(head(acq))` for more concrete advice - you may need to pre-process your data first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about parallelizing? This is an example based on your code:

```
library(parallel)

n_cores <- 2 # number of cores for parallel processing
cl <- makeCluster(n_cores)
emp <- parSapply(cl, 1:length(acq), FUN=function(x,i) str_detect(acq[[x]]$content,kw[I]))
stopCluster(cl)
```